# При выводе на печать элемент не отображается

Tags: html, печать, leafletjs

При нажатии кнопки "Печать" в браузере появляется пре-принт элемента - на одной странице описание объекта, на другой - его карта. Описание должно быть в книжной ориентации, а карта - в альбомной. Карту я печатаю с помощью [django_leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet).
На вертикальном листе она выводится, но слишком мелкая. А если добавить стиль с поворотом div'а, то вообще не отображается. В чём может быть причина?

```
 <!-- <div class='page' style='writing-mode: tb-rl;'> --> // отображается только заголовок
      <div class='page'>            // отображается всё, но вертикально.
          <div>
              <br>
              <p class='none' style='font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>
                  МЕСТОПОЛОЖЕНИЕ ОБЪЕКТА
              </p>
          </div>
          {% leaflet_map "map" callback='map_init_polygon' %}
          <script type="text/javascript"> 'use strict';
              ....
          </script>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `writing-mode` используется для текста. Для картинки есть

```
transform: rotate(270deg); // поворачивает изображение на 90 градусов влево.
```

или

```
transform: rotate(-90deg); // поворачивает изображение на 90 градусов влево.
```

Подробнее [здесь.](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform)